# YouTube is preventing Windows 11 from automatically locking screen after timer

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-11

My PC is set to lock itself after 60 minutes of inactivity. I have this set in screen saver and group policy.

But somehow when YouTube is playing a video on Chrome and is in focus it prevents Windows from locking the screen no matter how much times passes.

Any solutions?

Comment: 1. Does this happen only with Chrome? If so, use another browser. 2. If you want to force the PC to sleep after a time, use a third-party tool such as *Don'tSleep*, http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep , which has that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal and expected behavior from any browser in Windows today.

For how to try and manipulate this you would need to meddle along these lines;
https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/200808-turn-pc-put-sleep-when-watching-youtube-movie.html

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer.

Comment: This is essentially an statement to OP, lets call it question. With expanded answer to where he can get extra info. Should we all copy-paste something that is made?

Comment: A comment / link only answer is all it is.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I wont copy and claim someones work. Answer to question why is Youtube preventing Windows sleep, is as said:
That is normal and expected behavior from any browser in Windows today.

If that doesn't apply, I'll rather move answer to comment as Joep mentioned, than do what you asked.

Answer (score -1):

Change it from Windows Registry: REGEDIT

If you're comfortable with modifying the Windows Registry, you can make changes to the registry settings related to screen timeouts. Be cautious when editing the registry, as making incorrect changes can cause system issues.

Open the Registry Editor by pressing Win + R, typing `regedit`, and hitting Enter.

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7`.

Change the value of Attributes to 2.

Always create a backup of your registry before making any changes.